# Как работает данный код и метод equals?

Tags: java, equals

```
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Book book = (Book) o;
        return Objects.equals(title, book.title) && Objects.equals(author, book.author);
    }
```

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно в коде? Он же элементарен.

Comment: if (this == o) return true;// мы сравниваем объект с самим собой - зачем это делать?
 if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;// что здесь происходит?

Comment: `if (this == o)`: Объект, очевидно, должен быть равен сам себе, поэтому и сравниваем. `getClass() != o.getClass()`: Происходит проверка классов сравниваемых объектов. Обычно объекты разных классов неравны друг другу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего - это код, автоматически сгенерированный IntelliJ IDEA.
Он проверяет объект класса из которого он вызывается(т.е., класс, в котором он написан) и объект, который ему передается(`Object o`) на равенство.

- 1 строчка -  `if (this == o) return true;` - проверяет, равны ли объект класса в котором находится метод и переданный объект `о`.
- 2 строчка `if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;` проверяет, не равен ли переданный объект `null` и одинаковые ли у объектов типы(т.е., что бы корректно сравнить два объекта у них должны быть одинаковые типы. Если типы разные - возвр. false)

  `getClass` - получаем тип объекта, в классе которого находится `equals`, 
   `o.getClass` - получаем тип переданного объекта.
- 3 строчка `Book book = (Book) o;` - мы приводим объект `o` к типу `Book`.
- 4 строчка `Objects.equals(title, book.title) && Objects.equals(author, book.author);` - мы сравниваем два объекта по их полям. В данном случае мы сравниваем их по заголовкам книги или по авторам книги.